# C++ - Accepting user input as a function call

Tags: c++, command-line, command, user-input, function-call

I have a C++ program with six functions that perform actions on an implementation of a filesystem. I have no issue with these functions - this is a school project and my problem is in regards to the testing method. I need to accept "commands" that are basically function calls - such as "write(test.dat,128KB)" or "read(test.dat)".

I've found solutions to use a switch statement to call functions based on input, but since each command has its own parameters, this is not possible in my case. Is there any way to convert a user input to a function call? The only way I can think of is to parse the string and extract the function to be called and use a switch statement to call that function, and extract the arguments separately and pass those to the function - but this seems inefficient. Is it also possible that there is a completely different and better way to do this?

Comment: This is a design question. There are design patterns meant to specifically address these issues...strategy is a pattern that comes to my mind...

Answer (score 0):

Parse the command text.  You get a command name and arguments (probably all strings).

Look up the handler for the command.  It might have a 'validator' or 'argument type parser' stage, or it might just have an invocation.

Invoke the command, passing it the `vector` of arguments (either as strings, or as `boost::variant`s produced by the argument type parser).

The invoker can wrap a function with known parameters and translate the `vector` to a C++ call.  Fancy template metaprogramming could have this happen without writing it semi manually, but unless you have an industrial scale program may not be worth it.